# LC3 Assembly Language: skipping over function call

Tags: lc3

I am writing a program in LC3 that reads in a file of integers, squares each element and adds their squares up. I need the 'squaring' part to be in a function but in my while loop the call to my function is completely skipped over. So what I am getting is just the numbers in the file summed up without squaring them first. Any help appreciated, thank you!

```
; Program to calculate Euclidian sum of numbers stored at location x4000
;
.ORIG x3000
LD R1,a     ;first element address
LD R2,zero  ;ans -> R2 initialized to 0



;while (R1 isn't zero)

LOOP: LDR R4,R1,#0  ;element -> R4
      ADD R4,R4,-1  
      BRn DONE      ;if R1 < 0, condition fails

;loop body
LDR R4,R1,#0    ;element ->R4
LDR R5,R1,#0    ;counter
JSR SQUARE  
ADD R2,R2,R4    ;ans = ans + element
ADD R1,R1,#1    ;prepare for next element

BR LOOP     ;another iteration


ST R2,ans   ;result to ans

;
TRAP x25    ;exit

SQUARE
    ADD R4,R5,#0    ;R4 <- multiplier
    AND R6,R6,#0    ;R3 <- 0, sq
;inner loop
AGAIN
    ADD R6,R6,R4    
    ADD R5,R5,#-1   ;decerement counter
    BRp AGAIN   ;check end of calculation
    RET

;
zero .FILL 0 
a    .FILL x4000    ;a has the address of first location
ans  .BLKW 1        ;reserve location for ans
DONE  HALT      ;halt
.END
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your program.

#### Reading from the wrong register after return

Let's look at this SQUARE subroutine:

```
SQUARE
    ADD R4,R5,#0    ;R4 <- multiplier
    AND R6,R6,#0    ;R3 <- 0, sq
;inner loop
AGAIN
    ADD R6,R6,R4    
    ADD R5,R5,#-1   ;decerement counter
    BRp AGAIN   ;check end of calculation
    RET
```

You don't have any comments here about how the subroutine should be called, or what it returns. This makes it difficult to see what's wrong. Here's what you should write above this subroutine:

```
; SQUARE subroutine
; Squares an integer value
;
; Parameters:
;     R5: Value to be squared
; Return value:
;     R6: Squared value
; Notes:
;     This subroutine tramples R4
```

Why? If you're trying to debug the calling code, it's much easier to do so if you know how the subroutine is supposed to be called, and what assumptions you made while writing it. For example, you might make a change to the outer loop to make use of R4 as a temporary variable, and be confused as to why that value is being overwritten. (If you want to really go the extra mile, also document whether the subroutine supports zero or negative values as an argument.)

Now that we have this comment, the issue in the main code is clear:

```
LDR R4,R1,#0    ;element ->R4
LDR R5,R1,#0    ;counter
JSR SQUARE  
ADD R2,R2,R4    ;ans = ans + element
```

We load the value to be squared into R5, and call SQUARE. Then, SQUARE writes the squared value into R6, and we... load the value from R4. That's not correct. It should load from R6, not R4.

(As a side issue, `LDR R4,R1,#0` is unnecessary here, because the SQUARE subroutine ignores the value in R4. Another benefit of commenting your code!)

So we can correct this code to:

```
LDR R5,R1,#0    ;counter
JSR SQUARE  
ADD R2,R2,R6    ;ans = ans + element
```

#### DONE does not store to ans

Let's look at the outer loop condition:

```
LOOP  LDR R4,R1,#0  ;element -> R4
      ADD R4,R4,-1  
      BRn DONE      ;if R1 < 0, condition fails
```

So we load from the address pointed to by R1, and check if the value is less than or equal to zero. (The comment is incorrect, by the way.)

So what is at DONE?

```
DONE  HALT      ;halt
```

It halts immediately, without storing R2 to your result!

So, the fix is to move the line which stores to R2, so that it's run after you branch to DONE.

```
DONE
    ST R2, ans
    HALT      ;halt
```

---

Here's a complete code listing of the fixed program:

```
; Program to calculate Euclidian sum of numbers stored at location x4000
;
.ORIG x3000
LD R1,a     ;first element address
LD R2,zero  ;ans -> R2 initialized to 0



;while (R1 isn't zero)

LOOP
    LDR R4,R1,#0  ;element -> R4
    ADD R4,R4,-1  
    BRn DONE      ;if R1 < 0, condition fails

;loop body
    LDR R5,R1,#0    ;counter
    JSR SQUARE  
    ADD R2,R2,R6    ;ans = ans + element
    ADD R1,R1,#1    ;prepare for next element

    BR LOOP     ;another iteration

; SQUARE subroutine
; Squares an integer value
;
; Parameters:
;     R5: Value to be squared
; Return value:
;     R6: Squared value
; Notes:
;     This subroutine tramples R4
SQUARE
    ADD R4,R5,#0    ;R4 <- multiplier
    AND R6,R6,#0    ;R3 <- 0, sq
;inner loop
AGAIN
    ADD R6,R6,R4    
    ADD R5,R5,#-1   ;decerement counter
    BRp AGAIN   ;check end of calculation
    RET

;
zero .FILL 0 
a    .FILL x4000    ;a has the address of first location
ans  .BLKW 1        ;reserve location for ans
DONE
    ST R2, ans
    HALT      ;halt
.END
```

Here's how I tested the fixed program:

```
$ lc3sim -quiet prog_fixed.obj
   x0289  x0FFB                     BRNZP  TRAP_LOOP
Loaded "prog_fixed.obj" and set PC to x3000
(lc3sim) memory x4000 3
Wrote x0003 to address x4000.
(lc3sim) continue
   x0289  x0FFB                     BRNZP  TRAP_LOOP
(lc3sim) translate ans
Address ans has value x0009.
```